# Best way to assign actions to links in an ajax popup with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

My application is written in PHP and uses jQuery.

I have a popup dialog that is pulled in via AJAX.

```
<a href="#" id="loadpopup">
<div class="popup"></div>
<script>
$(function({
  $('a.loadpopup').click(function({
    $('div.popup').load("ajax/popup.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

On that dialog I have a few controls ( tags) to which I want to assign functions.

```
<h1>Popup dialog</h1>
<a href="#" class="dosomething">Do something!</a>
```

Normally I would try:

```
$(function({
  $('a.dosomething').click(function() { alert('hi'); });
});
```

But if I put this code on the main page, it is executed before the AJAX dialog is loaded - and consequently doesn't apply to the `<a>` tags in the dialog, and if I put it in the code sent via AJAX, it is not executed at all on a number of mobile devices.

I tried using a popup plugin called Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) which has a callback `ajaxContentLoaded()` which is great - but this is also never executed on an iPad or iPhone and the developer has not responded.

What I'm asking is: what is the best, most device-compatible way to assign actions to links in a popup loaded by AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I usually write the function that is to be executed in a script that loads when the page is loaded.

eg. my_scripts.js

```
function do_something(){
  // do something
}
```

then assign it to the particular element when loading the AJAX, by ending the ajax bit with a jquery function

eg. my_ajax_html.html

```
<p>Ajax content</p>
<a id="my_element">click me</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my_element").click(function(){
            do_something();
        });
    });
</script>
```

the difference is that the function is available in the DOM as a javascript function so the ajax content will be able to call it.

I never had a problem with this but let me know if you have a problem.